# Ruby IRC Server / Client

Tags: ruby, client, irc

Is it possible to programm a custom IRC chat server / client in Ruby?

- Is there any good documentation out there?
  (I mean the rfc docs are pretty much unreadable...)
- Or are there any tutorials?

Comment: Great ! Was not sure about it. ^^ Do you have any advice / tutorial / documentation that could be helfull ? thanks for your quick answer !

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/ and http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1459

Comment: Thanks for the Programming in Ruby link, for the rfc doc, like I said in my original post, it's really unreadable...but i will try ! ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/irc_bots

Comment: I don't want to creat a bot, I just want to creat the server / client part of it. Is "Autumn" in your link a framework for this use or only ofr the bot purpose ? thx !

Comment: Grab a Bot and apply some common sense to extract the client code.

Comment: Thx for the advice but manner up next time !

Comment: Don't confuse StackOverflow with a site where you get work done for free.

Comment: I was not asking for any work, I was ony asking for help on an IRC server... Sad to see that stackoverflow turn into this. :C